# Python: Fastest way of finding minimum and maximum per column in array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

**My problem**

Imagine I have

```
array1 = np.array([ [1,2] , [3,4], [4,5] ])
array2 = np.array([ [2,5] , [1,4], [8,1] ])
# .... and so on until arrayn
```

Where the first column we call it "x" and the second column we call it "y" . And then I group them in an container.

```
myList = [array1, array2,..., arrayn]
```

Now what is the fastest way of finding the minimum and maximum x values and the mimimum and maximu y value of the whole arrayList? (i.e. among all the arrays)

**My really slow try**

```
newarray = np.array([[np.array([i[:,j].min() for i in myList]).min(), np.array([i[:,j].max() for i in myList]).max()] for j in range(2)])
```

Is there something better?

Comment: Are all `array1, array2,..., arrayn` of the same shapes?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for not specifying, yes they have the same shape. Imagine 3 x 2

Comment: Then `arrayList` would be a regular array and hence, simply do : `arrayList.min(axis=(0,1)); arrayList.max(axis=(0,1))`, with `arrayList = np.array(myList)`.

Comment: it doesn't become an array!

Comment: oh wait yes it does!

Comment: Can you explain why it works?

Comment: With `np.array([array1, array2,..., arrayn])`, we are stacking the arrays along the first axis giving us a 3D array. With your loop code, you are finding min/max among all elements per index along the last axis. That is equivalent of min/max reduction along the first two axes of the 3D array.

Comment: Do you think yours is faster? And also, if my goal was to stuck this info into a "boundary form", would `np.array([ [a,b] for a,b in zip(arrayList.min(axis=(0,1)), arrayList.min(axis=(0,1)))])` be the fastest way?

Comment: Depends on - 1) How many arrays to be stacked. 2) No. of elements for reduction, among others.

Comment: the arrays in the arrayList would be around 40k, each of these arrays (for instance array1) would be around 80x2

Comment: A better way could be : `np.column_stack(( arrayList.min(axis=(0,1)), arrayList.max(axis=(0,1)) ))`. I would suggest timing those at your end and see for yourself.

Comment: Okay thank you! If you want to leave an answer, I will accept it!

Comment: Check out the alternative solution posted in my post. Would love to hear if its any better!

Comment: Any feedback on the alternative solution?

Comment: Not yet sorry, I will try it out on Monday!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `arrayList = np.array(myList)` being the `3D` input array of the stacked list of `2D` arrays, we could simply use `min/max` ufunc reductions on the array data and then stack those in columns. In the loopy code, we were finding the `min/max` among all elements for each index along the last axis, so the equivalent reductions would be for the first two axes in the `3D` stacked array.

Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
np.column_stack(( arrayList.min(axis=(0,1)), arrayList.max(axis=(0,1)) ))
```

The bottleneck with the above method could be the list to array conversion. So, we could avoid that with a loop comprehension to perform one level of `min/max` reduction and then one more to cover for all input arrays - `1,2..n`. Thus, an alternative solution would be -

```
minn = np.min([i.min(0) for i in myList],axis=0)
maxn = np.max([i.max(0) for i in myList],axis=0)
out = np.column_stack(( minn, maxn ))
```